# Backbone + jQuery + Tornado: OPTIONS request "Load canceled"

Tags: jquery, python, backbone.js, tornado, cors

I am using Backbone and jQuery on the front and have an API using Python/Tornado. Because my API is at http://api.domain.com and the site is at http://domain.com when I try to save a Backbone model it does an OPTIONS request first. The problem is it says "Load canceled" even though the server returned a valid response.

Request Headers:

```
OPTIONS /user/xdfr456890sd HTTP/1.1
Host: api.domain.com
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: PUT
Origin: http://domain.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, content-type, accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://domain.com/settings
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Response Headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Dec 2012 05:41:51 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
Server: TornadoServer/2.4
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://domain.com
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, POST, GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Charset,     Access-Control-Request-Headers, X-Scheme, Connection, Accept, User-Agent, Access-Control-Request-Method, Host, Referer, X-Real-Ip
```

Am I missing something? Doing something wrong? I have experimented with every possible combination of response headers and their values. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is whatever the `Origin` request header is.

Comment: Looks like these headers need to be returned on all requests and not just the OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 1):

You have listed methods

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: PUT, DELETE, POST, GET
```

But then you make a call with `OPTIONS` method that is not listed above

Comment: I have tried with and without the 'OPTION' request listed. This example just happen to come from when I was trying it without.

Comment: is it OPTION or OPTIONS? I see OPTIONS in chrome request method

Comment: @HadiFarnoud you are right, HTTP method is plural - OPTIONS. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods 
I will update my answer